# Am I to blame for not leveling up?

Tags: dnd-5e

In a prior DnD Session I had attempted to forge a document to help gain information for the good of the party which I thought was creative, which I rolled fairly high, however I was out rolled. This lead to my character being put in jail for a week and forced to play a NPC for 4 sessions.

Previous to the being put in jail, the playgroup was coming back from a break so we had a year of in game time recuperating from adventures. During the time I was playing an NPC, the party leveled up, and when I asked if my main character leveled, the answer was no as he wasn't present.

Is the fault of mine for trying to be creative? The group was Lvl 7 before the rest got a Level up if that matters.

Comment: I’m not sure “whose fault is it” is going to be a productive question; that tends to follow disguised rants, which don’t really have a place on SE. If this situation is generating unwanted tensions or hurt feelings, then “how to avoid this in the future” would likely be a much more answerable question. Is that what’s happening here?